# Please how I do fix [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config.settings']?

Tags: python, django

I have already installed pip requests, installed config file but it keeps showing the same thing.I even created a new virtual world and a new project but anytime I run "python manage.py runserver" or "python manage.py migrate" it keeps tell me (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config.settings').

pip install requests

Comment: Inside your Django protect, is there a directory called config with a file named settings.py inside? There should be.

Comment: You need to update Django version 5.

Comment: Ok, thanks i have done it and it is working